# I want to implement manager class. So when we create user, we can define manager and under that defined manager we will create user

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin, flask-security

```
roles users = db.Table(
    'roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)
```

Above mentioned code is for roles_users table

```
class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Above mentioned code build Role table and returns name of specific
role(SuperAdmin, Admin, User)

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    managername = db.Column(db.String(20))
    managers = db.relationship('Manager', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Class User for user database

```
class Manager(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Manager %r>' %(self.username)
```

class manager for manager database

```
 user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role, Manager)
 security = Security(app, user_datastore)
```

****user_datastore =SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role, Manager)
TypeError: **init**() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were
given**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using flask-security - which of course has no concept of 'Manager' - so there isn't any reason to pass that class to flask-security constructor. The rest of the definition looks reasonable - so possibly a better question would be to describe what you are trying to do with your manager class in terms of authorization. Possibly, flask-security's support for permissions within roles would get you going in the right direction - Manager's could be given a role that has some extra permissions.... just conjecture.

Comment: Then what can be the possible solution if we want to code manager class and put it in admin panel so superadmin can create manager.